# Call onclick datepicker function python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new to selenium and I'm trying to pass the values into the form. Although I am able to pass the values in the normal text box, I couldn't succeed in the onclick datepicker function. Here is the code.

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C://Users//phantomjs//bin//phantomjs.exe")
driver.get('https://enquiry.icegate.gov.in/enquiryatices/sbTrack')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('sbTrack_location'))
select.select_by_value("MUNDRA SEA (INMUN1)")
sb_no = driver.find_element_by_name("SB_NO")
sb_no.send_keys(7353156)
sb_dt = driver.find_element_by_name("SB_DT")
sb_dt.send_keys("2017/07/14")

driver.save_screenshot("test1_scr.png")
```

I am unable to send keys to tag with `readonly input` property from [here](https://enquiry.icegate.gov.in/enquiryatices/sbTrack).

```
<input type="text" name="SB_DT" value="" readonly="readonly" id="sbDATE">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the given [Website](https://enquiry.icegate.gov.in/enquiryatices/sbTrack) to select today's date e.g. **2018/03/26** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='/enquiryatices/image/Dateicon.gif']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='dpTable']//td/div[@class='dpDayHighlight']").click()
```

---

### Update

As per your comment to pass customized dates e.g. **2017/07/14** you have to remove the attribute **readonly="readonly"** and then send the date as text as follows :

```
sb_dt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='sbDATE']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", sb_dt);
sb_dt.send_keys("2017/07/14")
```

Comment: how can I pass my own dates say "2017/07/14" @DebanjanB

Comment: Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Great! It is working and one more doubt how can I submit the form and get the resultant page codes